# Using 2 dimensional COleSafeArray with variant values

Tags: atl

I need to return a two dimensional array from my MFC ATL, the values can be anything from Date, int, long, etc....
I created this:

```
COleSafeArray results;
long index[2] = {0,0};
DWORD numOfElements[] = {2,5};  
results.Create(VT_VARIANT,2, numOfElements);
results.PutElement(index,"some string"); // error happen here
```

I am not sure how I go about creating an array of variants and or using one, would appreciate some sample code if possible.

Comment: I believe you need something like `results.PutElement(index, &COleVariant("some string"));`

Comment: Whta is `PutElement`'s error code?

Comment: Igor, how do I use this with a string coming from .NET ?